# Change default file name for Windows Snipping Tool

Tags: windows-10

I am looking to change the default file name for snips created by the Windows Snipping Tool. See below for a screenshot of the *Save* window:

[image: Screenshot of save window]

I would like to be able to change the default file name from `Capture.PNG` to something else, like `Capture-Timestamp.PNG` where ***Timestamp*** is the current date and time.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the default filename is not supported with the Snipping Tool. Consider using a third-party utility, such as [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) or [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 has a new built-in snipping tool (Win + Shift + S) that saves the snippet directly to the clipboard and if you then save it, the default name contains the date, e.g:
"Annotation 2020-08-11 132909.png"

original [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/734004/snipping-tool-in-windows-7-10-save-images-with-lowercase-png-file-extension#answer-734187)